# Find the set of values of $p$ for which the equation $|\ln x|-px=0$ possess three distinct roots.

Tags: calculus

Find the set of values of $p$ for which the equation $|\ln x|-px=0$ possess three distinct roots.

---

$|\ln x|-px=0\Rightarrow|\ln x|=px$
I drew the graph of $|\ln x|$ and see that the line $px$ passing through origin always cuts the $|\ln x|$ at its branch before $x=1$.For $px$ to cut the $|\ln x|$ at two points,the slope of $px$ should be less than the slope of the tangent of $|\ln x|$
$p<\frac{1}{x}$
I am stuck here.What should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $0<p<e$ then $|\ln x|-px=0$ possess three distinct roots.

$$y=\ln x$$
$$y-y_0=k(x-x_0)$$
$$y- \ln x_0=\frac 1{x_0}(x-x_0)$$
$$y=\frac x{x_0}+\ln x_0-1$$
Then $\frac 1{x_0}=p$ and $\ln x_0-1=0$. Then $x_0=e$ and $p=\frac 1e$

[image]